# URGENT || Clear Order IDs

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, quote

We have recently suffered issues on our `Magento 2.1.8` store which has resulted in our customers not being able to place any orders. We think this issue has now been fixed, however some customers who have already tried to checkout still cannot check out as their Order ID is persisting as Magento thinks that the order has not been fulfilled yet it is still a valid order ID.

Is there a way that we can possibly retract all Order IDS from all customers whose order has not yet been successful so they Magento can generate them a new ID the next time they checkout?

Thanks.

Comment: Try after clear all entry from `quote` table from database. Query: __`DELETE FROM 'quote';`__

Comment: Is it safe to truncate this table? Also, setting them to **`is_active`** - "0" same as deleting?

Comment: I have now truncated this table. I will just need to continue to check the logs and see if the issue has been rectified

Comment: @BareFeet Yes __is_active - "0"__ is same as deleting entries. But truncate `quote` table only remove generated quotes(All added cart items) which clear all quotes(Cart items) from all the customers. Nothing else :)